# Functions in header file undefined

Tags: c, raylib

Im trying to make a Tilemap system in C using Raylib. My problem is that I walways get this error when trying to use a function from my Tilemap header file: `undefined reference to 'Tilemap_Init'` For some reason the structs work fine, but the funktions are just not working.

I already searched online, but I couldn't find anything that helped me. Heres my code:

Tilemap.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "H/Tilemap.h"
#include "raylib.h"

Tilemap* Tilemap_Init(void){
    Tilemap* tilemap;
    tilemap->tiles = malloc(1 * sizeof(Tile));
    tilemap->arrUsed = 0;
    tilemap->arrSize = 1;
    return tilemap;
}

void Tilemap_Destroy(Tilemap* tilemap){
    free(tilemap->tiles);
    tilemap->tiles = NULL;
    tilemap->arrUsed = tilemap->arrSize = 0;
}

void Tilemap_AddTile(Tilemap* tilemap, Tile tile){
    if(tilemap->arrUsed == tilemap->arrSize){
        tilemap->arrSize += 2;
        tilemap->tiles = realloc(tilemap->tiles, tilemap->arrSize * sizeof(Tile));
    }
    tilemap->tiles[tilemap->arrUsed++] = tile;
}

void Tilemap_SetTile(Tilemap* tilemap, Tile tile){
    for (int i = 0; i < tilemap->arrUsed; i++)
    {
        if(tilemap->tiles[i].position.x == tile.position.x){
            if(tilemap->tiles[i].position.y == tile.position.y){
                tilemap->tiles[i] = tile;
            }
        }
    }
    Tilemap_AddTile(tilemap, tile);
}

void Tilemap_Render(Tilemap* tilemap){
    for (int i = 0; i < tilemap->arrUsed; i++)
    {
        Tile tile = tilemap->tiles[i];

        Rectangle sourceRec = {0.0f, 0.0f, tile.texture.width, tile.texture.height};
        Rectangle destRec = {tile.position.x, tile.position.y, tile.texture.width, tile.texture.height};
        Vector2 origin = {tile.texture.width, tile.texture.height};
        DrawTexturePro(tile.texture, sourceRec, destRec, origin, 0.0f, WHITE);
    }
}
```

Tilemap.h

```
#ifndef TILEMAP_H
#define TILEMAP_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {            // Prevents name mangling of functions
#endif

#include "raylib.h"

typedef struct
{
    Vector2 position;
    Texture2D texture;
} Tile;


typedef struct
{
    Tile* tiles;
    int arrUsed;
    int arrSize;
} Tilemap;

Tilemap* Tilemap_Init(void);
extern void Tilemap_Destroy(Tilemap* tilemap);
void Tilemap_AddTile(Tilemap* tilemap, Tile tile);
void Tilemap_SetTile(Tilemap* tilemap, Tile tile);
void Tilemap_Render(Tilemap* tilemap);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

main.c

```
#include "raylib.h"

#include "Scripts/H/Tilemap.h"

int main() 
{
    // Initialization
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    const int screenWidth = 800;
    const int screenHeight = 450;

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "raylib");

    Tilemap* tilemap = Tilemap_Init();

    SetTargetFPS(60);               // Set our game to run at 60 frames-per-second
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Main game loop
    while (!WindowShouldClose())    // Detect window close button or ESC key
    {
        // Update
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Draw
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        BeginDrawing();

            ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
            DrawFPS(10, 10);

        EndDrawing();
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }
    // De-Initialization
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CloseWindow();        // Close window and OpenGL context
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    return 0;
}
```

and the Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all clean

# Define required raylib variables
PROJECT_NAME       ?= ProjectStarlight
RAYLIB_VERSION     ?= 3.0.0
RAYLIB_API_VERSION ?= 300
RAYLIB_PATH        ?= ..\..

# Define compiler path on Windows
COMPILER_PATH      ?= C:/raylib/mingw/bin

# Define default options
# One of PLATFORM_DESKTOP, PLATFORM_RPI, PLATFORM_ANDROID, PLATFORM_WEB
PLATFORM           ?= PLATFORM_DESKTOP

# Locations of your newly installed library and associated headers. See ../src/Makefile
# On Linux, if you have installed raylib but cannot compile the examples, check that
# the *_INSTALL_PATH values here are the same as those in src/Makefile or point to known locations.
# To enable system-wide compile-time and runtime linking to libraylib.so, run ../src/$ sudo make install RAYLIB_LIBTYPE_SHARED.
# To enable compile-time linking to a special version of libraylib.so, change these variables here.
# To enable runtime linking to a special version of libraylib.so, see EXAMPLE_RUNTIME_PATH below.
# If there is a libraylib in both EXAMPLE_RUNTIME_PATH and RAYLIB_INSTALL_PATH, at runtime,
# the library at EXAMPLE_RUNTIME_PATH, if present, will take precedence over the one at RAYLIB_INSTALL_PATH.
# RAYLIB_INSTALL_PATH should be the desired full path to libraylib. No relative paths.
DESTDIR ?= /usr/local
RAYLIB_INSTALL_PATH ?= $(DESTDIR)/lib
# RAYLIB_H_INSTALL_PATH locates the installed raylib header and associated source files.
RAYLIB_H_INSTALL_PATH ?= $(DESTDIR)/include

# Library type used for raylib: STATIC (.a) or SHARED (.so/.dll)
RAYLIB_LIBTYPE        ?= STATIC

# Build mode for project: DEBUG or RELEASE
BUILD_MODE            ?= RELEASE

# Use external GLFW library instead of rglfw module
# TODO: Review usage on Linux. Target version of choice. Switch on -lglfw or -lglfw3
USE_EXTERNAL_GLFW     ?= FALSE

# Use Wayland display server protocol on Linux desktop
# by default it uses X11 windowing system
USE_WAYLAND_DISPLAY   ?= FALSE

# Determine PLATFORM_OS in case PLATFORM_DESKTOP selected
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_DESKTOP)
    # No uname.exe on MinGW!, but OS=Windows_NT on Windows!
    # ifeq ($(UNAME),Msys) -> Windows
    ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
        PLATFORM_OS=WINDOWS
        export PATH := $(COMPILER_PATH):$(PATH)
    else
        UNAMEOS=$(shell uname)
        ifeq ($(UNAMEOS),Linux)
            PLATFORM_OS=LINUX
        endif
        ifeq ($(UNAMEOS),FreeBSD)
            PLATFORM_OS=BSD
        endif
        ifeq ($(UNAMEOS),OpenBSD)
            PLATFORM_OS=BSD
        endif
        ifeq ($(UNAMEOS),NetBSD)
            PLATFORM_OS=BSD
        endif
        ifeq ($(UNAMEOS),DragonFly)
            PLATFORM_OS=BSD
        endif
        ifeq ($(UNAMEOS),Darwin)
            PLATFORM_OS=OSX
        endif
    endif
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_RPI)
    UNAMEOS=$(shell uname)
    ifeq ($(UNAMEOS),Linux)
        PLATFORM_OS=LINUX
    endif
endif

# RAYLIB_PATH adjustment for different platforms.
# If using GNU make, we can get the full path to the top of the tree. Windows? BSD?
# Required for ldconfig or other tools that do not perform path expansion.
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_DESKTOP)
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),LINUX)
        RAYLIB_PREFIX ?= ..
        RAYLIB_PATH    = $(realpath $(RAYLIB_PREFIX))
    endif
endif
# Default path for raylib on Raspberry Pi, if installed in different path, update it!
# This is not currently used by src/Makefile. Not sure of its origin or usage. Refer to wiki.
# TODO: update install: target in src/Makefile for RPI, consider relation to LINUX.
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_RPI)
    RAYLIB_PATH       ?= /home/pi/raylib
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_WEB)
    # Emscripten required variables
    EMSDK_PATH          ?= C:/emsdk
    EMSCRIPTEN_VERSION  ?= 1.38.31
    CLANG_VERSION       = e$(EMSCRIPTEN_VERSION)_64bit
    PYTHON_VERSION      = 2.7.13.1_64bit\python-2.7.13.amd64
    NODE_VERSION        = 8.9.1_64bit
    export PATH         = $(EMSDK_PATH);$(EMSDK_PATH)\clang\$(CLANG_VERSION);$(EMSDK_PATH)\node\$(NODE_VERSION)\bin;$(EMSDK_PATH)\python\$(PYTHON_VERSION);$(EMSDK_PATH)\emscripten\$(EMSCRIPTEN_VERSION);C:\raylib\MinGW\bin:$$(PATH)
    EMSCRIPTEN          = $(EMSDK_PATH)\emscripten\$(EMSCRIPTEN_VERSION)
endif

# Define raylib release directory for compiled library.
# RAYLIB_RELEASE_PATH points to provided binaries or your freshly built version
RAYLIB_RELEASE_PATH     ?= $(RAYLIB_PATH)/src

# EXAMPLE_RUNTIME_PATH embeds a custom runtime location of libraylib.so or other desired libraries
# into each example binary compiled with RAYLIB_LIBTYPE=SHARED. It defaults to RAYLIB_RELEASE_PATH
# so that these examples link at runtime with your version of libraylib.so in ../release/libs/linux
# without formal installation from ../src/Makefile. It aids portability and is useful if you have
# multiple versions of raylib, have raylib installed to a non-standard location, or want to
# bundle libraylib.so with your game. Change it to your liking.
# NOTE: If, at runtime, there is a libraylib.so at both EXAMPLE_RUNTIME_PATH and RAYLIB_INSTALL_PATH,
# The library at EXAMPLE_RUNTIME_PATH, if present, will take precedence over RAYLIB_INSTALL_PATH,
# Implemented for LINUX below with CFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath,$(EXAMPLE_RUNTIME_PATH)
# To see the result, run readelf -d core/core_basic_window; looking at the RPATH or RUNPATH attribute.
# To see which libraries a built example is linking to, ldd core/core_basic_window;
# Look for libraylib.so.1 => $(RAYLIB_INSTALL_PATH)/libraylib.so.1 or similar listing.
EXAMPLE_RUNTIME_PATH   ?= $(RAYLIB_RELEASE_PATH)

# Define default C compiler: gcc
# NOTE: define g++ compiler if using C++
CC = gcc

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_DESKTOP)
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),OSX)
        # OSX default compiler
        CC = clang
    endif
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),BSD)
        # FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, DragonFly default compiler
        CC = clang
    endif
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_RPI)
    ifeq ($(USE_RPI_CROSS_COMPILER),TRUE)
        # Define RPI cross-compiler
        #CC = armv6j-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi-gcc
        CC = $(RPI_TOOLCHAIN)/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
    endif
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_WEB)
    # HTML5 emscripten compiler
    # WARNING: To compile to HTML5, code must be redesigned 
    # to use emscripten.h and emscripten_set_main_loop()
    CC = emcc
endif

# Define default make program: Mingw32-make
MAKE = mingw32-make

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_DESKTOP)
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),LINUX)
        MAKE = make
    endif
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),OSX)
        MAKE = make
    endif
endif

# Define compiler flags:
#  -O0                  defines optimization level (no optimization, better for debugging)
#  -O1                  defines optimization level
#  -g                   include debug information on compilation
#  -s                   strip unnecessary data from build -> do not use in debug builds
#  -Wall                turns on most, but not all, compiler warnings
#  -std=c99             defines C language mode (standard C from 1999 revision)
#  -std=gnu99           defines C language mode (GNU C from 1999 revision)
#  -Wno-missing-braces  ignore invalid warning (GCC bug 53119)
#  -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE    use with -std=c99 on Linux and PLATFORM_WEB, required for timespec
CFLAGS += -Wall -std=c99 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -Wno-missing-braces

ifeq ($(BUILD_MODE),DEBUG)
    CFLAGS += -g -O0
else
    CFLAGS += -s -O1
endif

# Additional flags for compiler (if desired)
#CFLAGS += -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_DESKTOP)
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),WINDOWS)
        # resource file contains windows executable icon and properties
        # -Wl,--subsystem,windows hides the console window
        CFLAGS += $(RAYLIB_PATH)/src/raylib.rc.data -Wl,--subsystem,windows
    endif
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),LINUX)
        ifeq ($(RAYLIB_LIBTYPE),STATIC)
            CFLAGS += -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE
        endif
        ifeq ($(RAYLIB_LIBTYPE),SHARED)
            # Explicitly enable runtime link to libraylib.so
            CFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath,$(EXAMPLE_RUNTIME_PATH)
        endif
    endif
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_RPI)
    CFLAGS += -std=gnu99
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_WEB)
    # -Os                        # size optimization
    # -O2                        # optimization level 2, if used, also set --memory-init-file 0
    # -s USE_GLFW=3              # Use glfw3 library (context/input management)
    # -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1   # to allow memory resizing -> WARNING: Audio buffers could FAIL!
    # -s TOTAL_MEMORY=16777216   # to specify heap memory size (default = 16MB)
    # -s USE_PTHREADS=1          # multithreading support
    # -s WASM=0                  # disable Web Assembly, emitted by default
    # -s EMTERPRETIFY=1          # enable emscripten code interpreter (very slow)
    # -s EMTERPRETIFY_ASYNC=1    # support synchronous loops by emterpreter
    # -s FORCE_FILESYSTEM=1      # force filesystem to load/save files data
    # -s ASSERTIONS=1            # enable runtime checks for common memory allocation errors (-O1 and above turn it off)
    # --profiling                # include information for code profiling
    # --memory-init-file 0       # to avoid an external memory initialization code file (.mem)
    # --preload-file resources   # specify a resources folder for data compilation
    CFLAGS += -Os -s USE_GLFW=3 -s TOTAL_MEMORY=16777216 --preload-file resources
    ifeq ($(BUILD_MODE), DEBUG)
        CFLAGS += -s ASSERTIONS=1 --profiling
    endif

    # Define a custom shell .html and output extension
    CFLAGS += --shell-file $(RAYLIB_PATH)/src/shell.html
    EXT = .html
endif

# Define include paths for required headers
# NOTE: Several external required libraries (stb and others)
INCLUDE_PATHS = -I. -I$(RAYLIB_PATH)/src -I$(RAYLIB_PATH)/src/external

# Define additional directories containing required header files
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_RPI)
    # RPI required libraries
    INCLUDE_PATHS += -I/opt/vc/include
    INCLUDE_PATHS += -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux
    INCLUDE_PATHS += -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_DESKTOP)
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),BSD)
        # Consider -L$(RAYLIB_H_INSTALL_PATH)
        INCLUDE_PATHS += -I/usr/local/include
    endif
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),LINUX)
        # Reset everything.
        # Precedence: immediately local, installed version, raysan5 provided libs -I$(RAYLIB_H_INSTALL_PATH) -I$(RAYLIB_PATH)/release/include
        INCLUDE_PATHS = -I$(RAYLIB_H_INSTALL_PATH) -isystem. -isystem$(RAYLIB_PATH)/src -isystem$(RAYLIB_PATH)/release/include -isystem$(RAYLIB_PATH)/src/external
    endif
endif

# Define library paths containing required libs.
LDFLAGS = -L. -L$(RAYLIB_RELEASE_PATH) -L$(RAYLIB_PATH)/src

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_DESKTOP)
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),BSD)
        # Consider -L$(RAYLIB_INSTALL_PATH)
        LDFLAGS += -L. -Lsrc -L/usr/local/lib
    endif
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),LINUX)
        # Reset everything.
        # Precedence: immediately local, installed version, raysan5 provided libs
        LDFLAGS = -L. -L$(RAYLIB_INSTALL_PATH) -L$(RAYLIB_RELEASE_PATH)
    endif
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_RPI)
    LDFLAGS += -L/opt/vc/lib
endif

# Define any libraries required on linking
# if you want to link libraries (libname.so or libname.a), use the -lname
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_DESKTOP)
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),WINDOWS)
        # Libraries for Windows desktop compilation
        # NOTE: WinMM library required to set high-res timer resolution
        LDLIBS = -lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm
        # Required for physac examples
        #LDLIBS += -static -lpthread
    endif
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),LINUX)
        # Libraries for Debian GNU/Linux desktop compiling
        # NOTE: Required packages: libegl1-mesa-dev
        LDLIBS = -lraylib -lGL -lm -lpthread -ldl -lrt
        
        # On X11 requires also below libraries
        LDLIBS += -lX11
        # NOTE: It seems additional libraries are not required any more, latest GLFW just dlopen them
        #LDLIBS += -lXrandr -lXinerama -lXi -lXxf86vm -lXcursor
        
        # On Wayland windowing system, additional libraries requires
        ifeq ($(USE_WAYLAND_DISPLAY),TRUE)
            LDLIBS += -lwayland-client -lwayland-cursor -lwayland-egl -lxkbcommon
        endif
        # Explicit link to libc
        ifeq ($(RAYLIB_LIBTYPE),SHARED)
            LDLIBS += -lc
        endif
    endif
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),OSX)
        # Libraries for OSX 10.9 desktop compiling
        # NOTE: Required packages: libopenal-dev libegl1-mesa-dev
        LDLIBS = -lraylib -framework OpenGL -framework OpenAL -framework Cocoa
    endif
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),BSD)
        # Libraries for FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, DragonFly desktop compiling
        # NOTE: Required packages: mesa-libs
        LDLIBS = -lraylib -lGL -lpthread -lm

        # On XWindow requires also below libraries
        LDLIBS += -lX11 -lXrandr -lXinerama -lXi -lXxf86vm -lXcursor
    endif
    ifeq ($(USE_EXTERNAL_GLFW),TRUE)
        # NOTE: It could require additional packages installed: libglfw3-dev
        LDLIBS += -lglfw
    endif
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_RPI)
    # Libraries for Raspberry Pi compiling
    # NOTE: Required packages: libasound2-dev (ALSA)
    LDLIBS = -lraylib -lbrcmGLESv2 -lbrcmEGL -lpthread -lrt -lm -lbcm_host -ldl
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_WEB)
    # Libraries for web (HTML5) compiling
    LDLIBS = $(RAYLIB_RELEASE_PATH)/libraylib.bc
endif

# Define a recursive wildcard function
#rwildcard=$(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2) $(filter $(subst *,%,$2),$d))

# Define all source files required
#SRC_DIR = src
#OBJ_DIR = obj

# Define all object files from source files
#SRC = $(call rwildcard, *.c, *.h)

PROJECT_SOURCE_FILES ?= \
    main.c \
    Scipts/C/Tilemap.c

OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(PROJECT_SOURCE_FILES))
#OBJS = $(SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
#OBJS ?= main.c

# For Android platform we call a custom Makefile.Android
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_ANDROID)
    MAKEFILE_PARAMS = -f Makefile.Android 
    export PROJECT_NAME
    export SRC_DIR
else
    MAKEFILE_PARAMS = $(PROJECT_NAME)
endif

# Default target entry
# NOTE: We call this Makefile target or Makefile.Android target
all:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKEFILE_PARAMS)

# Project target defined by PROJECT_NAME
$(PROJECT_NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(PROJECT_NAME)$(EXT) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) -D$(PLATFORM)

# Compile source files
# NOTE: This pattern will compile every module defined on $(OBJS)
#%.o: %.c
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) -D$(PLATFORM)

# Clean everything
clean:
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_DESKTOP)
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),WINDOWS)
        del *.o *.exe /s
    endif
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),LINUX)
    find -type f -executable | xargs file -i | grep -E 'x-object|x-archive|x-sharedlib|x-executable' | rev | cut -d ':' -f 2- | rev | xargs rm -fv
    endif
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),OSX)
        find . -type f -perm +ugo+x -delete
        rm -f *.o
    endif
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_RPI)
    find . -type f -executable -delete
    rm -fv *.o
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_WEB)
    del *.o *.html *.js
endif
    @echo Cleaning done
```

Comment: I'm seeing no invocations of `Tilemap_Init` in the code you've shown, which makes me think the error is in a different file... Unrelated, but the initialisation of `tilemap` in `Tilemap_Init` will not work like that. You dereference an uninitialised pointer there.

Comment: Could the problem be in the makefile? I've never worked with makefiles before and I just used the example one from a raylib example, that uses multiple .c files. But I think that wouldn't make much sense, because I can use the structs in other .c files.

Comment: Show the source code that uses `Tilemap_Init` (reduce it to a [mre] if it is longer than a few lines). Show the commands you use to build, link, and run the program.

Comment: I just added the main.c file and the Makefile to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(PROJECT_SOURCE_FILES))
#OBJS = $(SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
#OBJS ?= main.c
```

This looks like an attempt to fix something gone wrong. Let's see:

```
(PROJECT_NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(PROJECT_NAME)$(EXT) $(OBJS) ...
```

So you have `main.c` and `Scipts/C/Tilemap.c`. The corresponding `OBJS` would be `main.o` and `Scipts/C/Tilemap.o`, because `patsubst` just substitutes `.c` with `.o`.  However...

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) -D$(PLATFORM)
```

This compiles `.c` file present in `$(SRC_DIR)` and puts the compilation result in `$(OBJ_DIR)`. Both these variables are commented out in your Makefile. This rule can neither compile both `main.c` and `Scipts/C/Tilemap.c` nor produce both `main.o` and `Scipts/C/Tilemap.o` as they reside in different directories.

In short, Makefile is broken.